# Postgres not using Covering Index with Aggregate

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

Engine version: 12.4

Postgres wasn't using index only scan, then I ran vacuum analyze verbose table_name. After that it started using index only scan. Earlier when I had ran analyze verbose table_name without vacuum that time index only scan wasn't used.

So it means there is very heavy dependency on vacuum to use index only plan. Is there any way to eliminate this dependency OR should we configure vacuum very regularly? frequency like daily.

Our objective is to reduce cpu usage.. Overall machine cpu usage is 10%-15% throughout the day but when this query runs then cpu goes very high( this query runs in multiple threads at same time with diff values)

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT COALESCE(requested_debit, 0) AS requestedDebit, COALESCE(requested_credit, 0) AS                                                                                             requestedCredit 
FROM (SELECT COALESCE(Sum(le.credit), 0) AS requested_credit, COALESCE(Sum(le.debit), 0) AS requested_debit 
FROM ledger_entries le 
WHERE le.accounting_entity_id = 1 
AND le.general_ledger_id = 503 
AND le.post_date BETWEEN '2020-09-10' AND '2020-11-30') AS requested_le;
                                                                                                      QUERY PLAN                                                                                                      
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Subquery Scan on requested_le  (cost=66602.65..66602.67 rows=1 width=64) (actual time=81.263..81.352 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Finalize Aggregate  (cost=66602.65..66602.66 rows=1 width=64) (actual time=81.261..81.348 rows=1 loops=1)
         ->  Gather  (cost=66602.41..66602.62 rows=2 width=64) (actual time=79.485..81.331 rows=3 loops=1)
               Workers Planned: 2
               Workers Launched: 2
               ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=65602.41..65602.42 rows=1 width=64) (actual time=74.293..74.294 rows=1 loops=3)
                     ->  Parallel Index Only Scan using post_date_gl_id_accounting_entity_id_include_idx on ledger_entries le  (cost=0.56..65203.73 rows=79735 width=8) (actual time=47.874..74.212 rows=197 loops=3)
                           Index Cond: ((post_date >= '2020-09-10'::date) AND (post_date <= '2020-11-30'::date) AND (general_ledger_id = 503) AND (accounting_entity_id = 1))
                           Heap Fetches: 0
 Planning Time: 0.211 ms
 Execution Time: 81.395 ms
(11 rows)
```

Comment: @laurenz : Helps are much appreciated

Comment: If auto vacuum can't keep up with your changes, you might need to make it more aggressive for the table in question (e.g. lower the thresholds when it kicks in, increase the work it does in a single run)

Answer (score 1):

There is a very strong connection between `VACUUM` and index-only scans in PostgreSQL: an index-only scan can only skip fetching the table row (to check for visibility) if the block containing the row is marked all-visible in the visibility map. And the visibility map is updated by `VACUUM`.

So yes, you have to `VACUUM` often to get efficient index-only scans.

Typically, there is no need to schedule a manual `VACUUM`, you can simply

```
ALTER TABLE mytab SET (autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor = 0.01);
```

(or a similar value) and let autovacuum do the job.

The only case where this is problematic are insert-only tables, because for them autovacuum won't be triggered for PostgreSQL versions below v13. In v13, you can simply change `autovacuum_vacuum_insert_scale_factor`, while in older versions you will have to set `autovacuum_freeze_max_age` to a low value for that table.